# Setting minimum upper y-lim and maximum lower y-lim in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm working with the axes objects for a pyplot chart.

What I am trying to do is have the the minimum size for the y-axis, such that the lower end of the axis cannot go above -1 and the upper end of the axis cannot go below 1, but I don't want to constrain an upper bound of the upper end of the axis, and a lower bound for the lower bound of the axis.

Is there a way where I can set the minimum upper bound of the axis and the reverse for the lower one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So once you perform a plot, just query the axes for the current limits, and extend them if needed.  Something like this:

```
ylim = axes.get_ylim()
new_ylim = (min(ylim[0],-1), max(ylim[1], 1) )
axes.set_ylim(new_ylim)
```

Comment: Exactly what I ended up doing. Seemed like this would be a feature that is native-ly supported, but searching didn't seem to turn up anything.

Comment: The autoscaling code is pretty complex as it is.  I suspect that the API to implement this functionality in a reliable, clear, configurable way would end up putting way more burden on the users to learn/remember than having users use this solution as needed.